# unix reorganize files into subdirectories based on name strings

Tags: file, unix, directory, subdirectory

I'm looking to move files (`abc1_gff`, `abc2_gff`, etc) from their current dir (`cds.gff`) to new, preexisting folders that match the "`abc#`" at the end of their names (`example_name_abc1`, `example_name_abc2`, etc). Here's a visual:

```
[Linux@vaughan test]$ tree
.
├── cds.gff
│   ├── abc1_cds
│   ├── abc1_cds.gff
│   ├── abc2_cds
│   ├── abc2_cds.gff
│   └── abc_cds
├── example_name_abc1
│   └── distraction_abc1.txt
├── example_name_abc2
│   └── abc2_distraction_abc2.txt
└── move_files.sh
```

Where I'd expect `abc1_cds.gff` to be moved into `example_name_abc1`, and `abc2_cds.gff` to be moved into `example_name_abc2` with no additional changes. I have the script `move_files.sh` here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate over files in the "cds.gff" directory
for file in cds.gff/*.gff; do
  # Extract the filename without the path
  filename="${file##*/}"

  # Extract the last part of the folder name
  last_part_of_folder="${filename%_cds.gff}"

  # Check if there's a matching folder in the current directory
  if [ -d "$last_part_of_folder" ]; then
    # Move the file to the matching folder
    mv "$file" "$last_part_of_folder/"
  fi
done
```

which yields no changes to any file locations after running `./move_files.sh` (and it's executable). Any thoughts welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not do what you seem to expect:

```
if [ -d "$last_part_of_folder" ]; then
```

If it testing if there is a directory with the literal name held in `$last_part_of_folder`; e.g., does a directory named `abc1` exist. You need to preface it with a wildcard:

```
if [ -d *_"$last_part_of_folder" ]; then
```

This, of course is risky if there is any chance of two (or more) directories having the same rightmost substring. You also need to make the same change to the `mv` command. Running this type of script with tracing enabled is often helpful: `bash -x path-to-script`.