# How to get subdir name in a directory then run curl command against the discovered name?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a CD ripping machine that rips music files into directories which is an album name.  Getting tired of manually importing these into my music management client. Trying unsuccessfully to get a bash script to find the album name then run a curl command across that directory or album name.

So basically the ripping machine extracts, renames and tags the folder and music files.
root dir /mnt/ripped_audio
sub dirs /mnt/ripped_audio/album_name/music_tracks

How can i use bash to get album_name since its always new name or unique every time ? Then run curl command across that album_name ?

I am close but my music management client cannot do recursive manual import items from root dir /mnt/ripped_audio it has to be /album_name/music_tracks for it to add the items. But i am struggling to figure this out in a script.

thanks for your time

Tried various forms of pwd and find commands but no luck.

Comment: An interesting problem, but sorry,  Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Please delete here and repost to [su] . 
Also, you have left a lot to the imagination here. It would really help to have a "diagram" of your directory layout, both as you want it and the current "pieces" that it is in (including a few sample track files both from your CD ripping machine and your music management software). Good luck.

Comment: I think this would be a valid question if it included the rest of the stuff from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - the code you tried so far and its actual results.  The more of a minimal reproducible example of current behavior you can find, the better the answers you're likely to get.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77217698/620097 for a (partial) example "diagram" of directories/files. Good luck.

Comment: Bash's command substitution might help: `basename $(dirname "/mnt/ripped_audio/album_name/music_tracks")`

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is a little unclear, not sure about what you want exactly. Could be better if you provide some examples.

But you can try finding newer album (folder) name based on "last modified time" via `find` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158235)):

```
find /mnt/ripped_audio -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -newermt 2023-10-03T14:00
```

where: (I assume folder structure is `/mnt/ripped_audio/{albums}/{tracks}`)

- only list 2 level deep as we just want get tracks.
- only list tracks newer than `2023-10-03T14:00` (can adjust yourself) as we only want newer albums.

And use `xargs` to do your `curl` job, for example:

```
find /mnt/ripped_audio -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -newermt 2023-10-03T14:00 | xargs -I {} echo "my tracks: {}"
```

- `{}` is a placeholder to the result from `find`.
- I use `echo` to demo, since not quite understand what you want to do with `curl`.

Note:

- You can use `basename` and `dirname` after the `xargs` to get filename and folder name respectively:

```
find /mnt/ripped_audio -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -newermt 2023-10-03T14:00 | xargs -I {} basename {}
find /mnt/ripped_audio -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -newermt 2023-10-03T14:00 | xargs -I {} dirname {}
```

- can use relative date via `date`. For example:

```
find /mnt/ripped_audio -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -newermt $(date -d '10 hours ago' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M)
```